# How to properly build a project with custom include files with MSVC (cl.exe)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, include, cl.exe

I have this program that randomizes source files and such and it's been working perfectly for the past two years. However, once I decided to use a third-party include/library like DirectX, cl.exe doesn't want to cooperate.

I have this as the arguments for `cl.exe` (after using vcvars)

```
/EHsc /Od /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK(June 2010)\Include" /MT *.cpp kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib /link /FORCE:MULTIPLE /OUT:Generated.exe
```

Whenever I run it, I get an error in the files that I included `<d3dx9.h>` in. I checked the directory listed and `'d3dx9.h'` is in fact in there.

This is the exact error:

```
D3D.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dx9.h': No such file or directory
```

When I compile the base project (the project that the randomized output is based on), it succeeds and runs perfectly. *Am I doing something wrong in the parameters?*